# Azure App Service hosting internal technology

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, iis, service, azure-appservice

When I host a .NET Core application in Azure App Service, it takes a `web.config` custom headers configuration, same as in IIS.

Which technology is used in the Azure App Service to host a .NET Core web application?

Comment: Azure App Service is just a name. Deep down inside, you can either host your web app on Windows (IIS) or Linux  or on Docker, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-hosting-plans When you said `web.config` takes effect, you were using the Windows based App Service hosting plan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you [Lex Li](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11182/lex-li) for your suggestion posting it as answer to help other community members .

"Azure app service is just a name.
you can either host your web app on Windows (IIS) or Linux or on Docker,  as you said `web.config` takes effect, you were using the **Windows based App Service** hosting plan."

- According to that when we host our application in Azure app service there will be no change in our application .

Please refer the below links for more information :

MS DOC :  [Quickstart: Deploy an ASP.NET web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/app-service/quickstart-dotnetcore?tabs=net60&pivots=development-environment-vs)

MS DOC:  [ASP.NET Web Deployment using Visual Studio: Web.config File Transformations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/web-config-transformations).

MS DOC :  [Troubleshoot ASP.NET Core on Azure App Service and IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/troubleshoot-azure-iis?view=aspnetcore-6.0)